# GridView. I need to push "Edit" link 2 times for starting update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to fix it?

I declared handlers in Page_Load, Page_PreRender and markup. It doesn't work normaly.

Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tableResults" runat="server" DataMember="Table" EnableModelValidation="True"
    CssClass="GridViewStyle" OnRowDeleting="dataViewRowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Скачать объект" NavigateUrl='<%#"objects/" + Eval("Идентификатор") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Handlers:

```
tableResults.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
tableResults.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(tableResults_RowEditing);
tableResults.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(tableResults_RowUpdating);
tableResults.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(tableResults_RowCancelingEdit);
```

Comment: I'm afraid more is needed to even attempt to trouble-shoot this. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I tried your code and got the same issue as you. The reason is because you are manually calling Databind in Page_Load but you are not reattaching the datasource. You need reattach your datasource in your edit event handler (as well as other event handlers).

```
protected void tableResults_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    tableResults.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    PopulateTableResults();   // In this method I attach the datasource and bind
}
```

If you don't want to do it manually you need to use the data source control.

Comment: I declared handlers in Page_Load, Page_PreRender and **markup**. I did it

Comment: your markup only showed OnRowDeleting = "dataViewRowDeleting" and AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True". Just add the rest to the markup like I have done and get rid of them from the Page_Load and Page_PreRender, then see if you are having the same problem. If you are then you will need to show more code.

Comment: you have to believe me. I did it. It was first what i did. And now i try it again.